# How can I set fetching Records from Amazon Advertising Api

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am beginner of Amazons Product Advertising API. How can I write code to Retrieve Limited Records from Amazon Advertising Api.

```
$amazonEcs = new AmazonECS(AWS_API_KEY, AWS_API_SECRET_KEY, 'DE', AWS_ASSOCIATE_TAG);
$amazonEcs->category($_GET['category']);
$amazonEcs->responseGroup('Large');
$amazonEcs->returnType(AmazonECS::RETURN_TYPE_ARRAY);
$amazonEcs->country($_GET['country']);
$page = (!empty($_GET['page'])) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1;
```